# How i can achieve this nav using jquery toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently i have made  this side navigation using target function of css3 but i want to know how i can do this with jquery without changing any interfernce of layout please help as soon as possilble
here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
@-webkit-keyframes nav {
    from {left:-100px;opacity: 0;}
    to {left:0px;opacity:1;}
}
@keyframes nav{
    from {left:-100px;opacity: 0;}
    to {left:0px;opacity:1;}
}

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:#EFEBE9;
}
.navigate {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:#FFF;
padding-bottom:1px solid #F6F6F6;
display:inline-block; 
position:fixed;
}
.navigate > .navicon {
width:2em;
height:100px;
background-color:#1565C0;
color:#FFF;
font-size:4em;
text-align:center;
}
.navigate > .navicon > a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
.menu {
display:none;
}
.menu:target {
display:table;
background-color:#0D47A1;
}
nav {
width:40%;
height:100%;
background-color:#1565C0;
position:absolute;
-webkit-animation-name:nav;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  animation-name:nav;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
.closebtn {
color:#FFF;
font-size:2.5em;
margin:.3em;
float:right;
text-decoration:none;
}
.closebtn > a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:1em;
color:#FFF;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigate">
<div class="navicon" onclick="window.location.href='#menu';" >☰</div>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu">
<nav>
<div class="closebtn"><a href="">✖</a></div>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls check http://jsfiddle.net/s1g5ccty/1/

Comment: hi, I've posted an answer below. I modified your css and make use of transition effect + jquery instead of an animation. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to modify your css code and added some jquery.

```
$('.navicon').click(function(){
    $('#menu nav').addClass('nav-open');
});
$('#menu .closebtn').click(function(){
    $('#menu nav').removeClass('nav-open');
});
```

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/btgqh3oe/1/

Comment: hey thanks but  can u do a pen on this so i can download it - a easy way

Comment: @SuhailInvento this is the pen I created from the fiddle I made: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYxVdO

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu').hide();
$('.navicon').click(function () {
    $('.menu').toggle('slow');
})
```

use `hide()` to hide the menu

then use `toggle()` to show and hide menu on button click

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s1g5ccty/1/)